# std::thread causes segmentation fault in Raspbian using gcc-linaro-4.9.4

Tags: c++, g++, raspbian, stdthread

I'm getting a segmentation fault on code that looks perfectly valid to me.

Here's a minimal recreating example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void func()
{
    /* do nothing; thread contents are irrelevant */
}

int main()
{
    for (unsigned idx = 0; idx < 1000; idx++)
    {
        std::thread t(func);
        void* buffer = malloc(1000);
        free(buffer);
        t.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I made a run with prints, to check which iteration fails; I got the segmentation fault on iteration #292.

I used gcc-linaro-4.9.4 (taken from here: https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/4.9-2017.01/arm-linux-gnueabihf/).

I compiled the program this way:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11 -lpthread -pthread main.cpp -o main.out
```

I tried recreating this in gcc-linaro-6.5, and didn't have the problem there.

Any idea why this happens?

### Edit 1

There is no warnings/errors when I compile this code.

Running it under strace reveals nothing special.

Running it under GDB reveals that the segmentation faults happens in `free` function:

```
Thread 1 "main.out" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_int_free (av=0x76d84794 <main_arena>, p=0x1e8bf, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4043
4043    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  _int_free (av=0x76d84794 <main_arena>, p=0x1e8bf, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4043
#1  0x00010bfa in main ()
```

Running it under valgrind reveals the following:

```
==361== Thread 2:
==361== Invalid read of size 4
==361==    at 0x4951D64: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
==361==  Address 0x4becf74 is 0 bytes after a block of size 28 alloc'd
==361==    at 0x4847D4C: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:328)
==361==    by 0x11629: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned int, void const*) (in /home/pi/main.out)
==361== 
==361== Invalid write of size 4
==361==    at 0x4951D6C: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
==361==  Address 0x4becf74 is 0 bytes after a block of size 28 alloc'd
==361==    at 0x4847D4C: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:328)
==361==    by 0x11629: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned int, void const*) (in /home/pi/main.out)
==361== 
==361== 
==361== HEAP SUMMARY:
==361==     in use at exit: 28,000 bytes in 1,000 blocks
==361==   total heap usage: 2,002 allocs, 1,002 frees, 1,048,368 bytes allocated
==361== 
==361== Thread 1:
==361== 28,000 bytes in 1,000 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==361==    at 0x4847D4C: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:328)
==361==    by 0x11629: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned int, void const*) (in /home/pi/main.out)
==361== 
==361== LEAK SUMMARY:
==361==    definitely lost: 28,000 bytes in 1,000 blocks
==361==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==361==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==361==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==361==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==361== 
==361== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==361== ERROR SUMMARY: 2017 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

### edit 2

I still get segmetation fault after I remove the `-lpthread` and `-std=c++11` compilation flags. This is the way I compiled it this time:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -std=gnu++11 -pthread main.cpp -o main.out
```

Comment: Have you used the debugger to inspect the issue? Run under `strace`? Under `valgrind`? What were the results? You have no errors nor warnings when compiling the code?

Comment: where the seg fault occurs, in _main_ of _func_ ? are you out of memory when the seg fault occurs ?

Comment: In your actual code, does `func()` do something? Does the *exact* code you posted above, produce a segmentation fault?

Comment: @idmean - The segmentation fault does happen in this code, it does not matter if `func()` actually do something or not.

Comment: @KamilCuk 
I'll run it with strace, gdb and valgrind and post results in 1-2 hours

Comment: @KamilCuk I edited the original question with the data you requested

Comment: `-std=c++11 -std=gnu++11 -lpthread -pthread` is odd, it should be just `-std=gnu++11 -pthread`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Tried it, still getting seg fault (edit 2). Thanks

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest it would fix anything, it's just better.

Comment: Your GDB and valgrind output point towards a bug in the runtime library. Is your `malloc` call required to reproduce the error or do the same errors occur without it?

Comment: @idmean Both `malloc` call and `std::thread` creation are required to reproduce the error. If I delete any of them the error does not reproduce

Comment: From inspecting the `gcc-linario-4.9.4-2017.01-arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz` there is `libc-2.19-2014.08-1-git.so` and `libstdc++.so.6.0.20`

Comment: I think we need to get more info... Can you post the output of `x/30i $pc` and `info registers` after segfault in gdb? Can you post the assembly of your compiled program? Does the bug persist with optimizations enabled? Can you add `#include <gnu/libc-version.h> cout<<gnu_get_libc_version()<<std::endl;` to the beginning of your program to 100% see the glibc version?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is a mismatch between your code and  the `libstdc++.so` library you're linking to.

One possibility is that the wrong `libstdc++.so` is being used at runtime, which you could check by using the `ldd` utility. The correct version for GCC 4.9.4 is `libstdc++.so.6.0.20` so if you see it linking to a different version, that's a problem.

The second possibility is that it's the right `libstdc++.so` but it is compiled with different settings from your code, and so the `std::thread` in your code uses atomic operations for `shared_ptr` reference counting, but the `std::thread` in the library uses a mutex (which is the same problem as described in [GCC Bug 42734](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42734)). If the crash and the valgrind errors go away when you compile your program with `-march=armv5t` then it  would confirm this is the problem.